# How to check nan value in pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas

```
  nan_rows = []
  
  for index, row in df.iterrows():
        topic = row['topic']
        if topic != np.nan:
            nan_rows.append(row)
```

I want to split my dataframe into two: if the 'topic' value is nan, then extract it out. But the code above doesn't work. Why is that?

Comment: By definition `np.NaN != np.NaN` is `True`. You can just `df.groupby(df.topic.isnull())`

Comment: `df[df['topics'].isna()]` for na rows, `df[df['topic'].notna()]` for those are not?

Comment: @ALollz how to make the result of groupby into a df ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal example how to group by `isnull()` and assign the two groups to a dataframe each.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'topic':[np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1]})

>>> df
   topic
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    NaN
3    1.0

grouper = df.groupby(df.topic.isnull())
>>> grouper.groups
{False: [1, 3], True: [0, 2]}

df_True = grouper.get_group(True)
>>> df_True
   topic
0    NaN
2    NaN 

df_False = grouper.get_group(False)
>>> df_False   
   topic
1    1.0
3    1.0
```